# Errors on code (state machine)

Tags: c, state-machine

I'm going a bit crazy trying to fix this code. I've been at it for almost two hours and I can't find what's wrong.

This is a simple program that should take some text as an input and return the same text with all the numbers switched from decimal to hex base.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int revNumber(int);

typedef enum { STATE_WORD, STATE_BLANK, STATE_NUMBER } state_t;

int main()
{
    int c;
    int readNum = 0;
    int writeNum = 0;
    int digit = 1;
    int sign = 1;

    state_t state = STATE_BLANK;

    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case STATE_WORD:
                if( isspace(c) )
                    state = STATE_BLANK;
                putchar(c);
                break;

            case STATE_BLANK:
                if(c == '-')
                {
                    sign = -1;
                    state = STATE_NUMBER;
                }
                else if( isdigit(c) )
                {
                    readNum += (c - '0') * digit;
                    digit *= 10;
                    state = STATE_NUMBER;
                }
                else if( isspace(c) )
                    putchar(c);

                else
                {
                    state = STATE_WORD;
                    putchar(c);
                }
                break;

            case STATE_NUMBER:
                if( isdigit(c) )
                {
                    readNum += (c - '0') * digit;
                    digit   *= 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    writeNum = revNumber(readNum);
                    readNum = 0;

                    if(sign == -1)
                        putchar('-');

                    if(digit > 1)
                    {
                        if( isspace(c) )
                        {
                            printf("%x", writeNum);
                            state = STATE_BLANK;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("%d", writeNum);
                            state = STATE_WORD;
                        }
                    }
                    digit = 1;
                    sign  = 1;
                    putchar(c);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}


int revNumber(int n)
{
    int revNum = 0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        revNum += revNum * 10 + n%10;
        n   /= 10;
    }
    return revNum;
}
```

The program, however, doesn't work correctly, for some reason I keep getting the conversion to hex wrong. Why does this happen? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any error code that you are getting after compile your code

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not getting compilation errors.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`.  That's not the cause of your problem, however.

Comment: Are there any parameters surrounding the input? As in, is the user expected to input in a certain way (e.g., with spaces between each individual word/number), or is it entirely arbitrary?

Comment: Well, my idea was to take, for example, the text "hi123 <-- not a number, but 345 is one" to "hi123 <-- not a number but 159 is one".

Comment: @tonysdg Still compiles just fine (I had only forgotten to put the return 0 on main).

Comment: Like I said - that's not the cause of your problem :) Why not read the entire input in as a string, use `strtok` to check each individual section for numbers (i.e. the string only includes numbers), and then parse those sections with something like `sprintf (buf, "%x", atoi ("345"))`?

Comment: Hmm I wanted to know what was wrong with this code, more than anything to be honest, as I'm quite lost on why it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Pro tip: You can make about 20 well named functions of the code you are posting. Doing so you might start understanding what you are actually doing, and then you will probably find you issue very easily.

Comment: Your `revNumber` function doesn't work. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I type `123` at the command line, your program is internally storing: `1*1 + 2*10 + 3*100 = 321` which is reversed, fine. But then, your function to reverse `321` returns `146` instead of `123`. Something is definitely wrong there.

I suggest looking at this for starters:

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-reverse-number

The problem is that this line:

`revNum += revNum * 10 + n%10;`

should be:

`revNum = revNum * 10 + n%10;`

If you are going to copy-pasta a function, you should at least verify that it works before relying on it in your code.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't copy-pasted that function, I made it, and kept looking at it thinking it worked fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just assumed you copy pasted because it's extremely similar to the one [here](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-reverse-number), even down to the weird spacing in `n    /= 10;`.

Answer (score 2):

the following code does not actually 2's compliment the number as hex values do not have a sign, only magnitude.

However, this works as expected (for every test case I used)

It demonstrates the preferred logic for handling a state machine, including how to easily handle state transitions.

the following code does not reverse the digits in the number, you should be able easily add that feature, which would replace the call to `printf()` in the `inNumber()` function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum { STATE_WORD, STATE_BLANK, STATE_NUMBER } state_t;


state_t inWord  ( char ch );
state_t inBlank ( char ch );
state_t inNumber( char ch );

int  number = 0;
char sign   = ' ';

state_t state = STATE_BLANK;


int main( void )
{
    int c;


    printf( "program will echo sentence with numeric sub strings output in hex format\n");
    printf( "Enter a sentence:");

    while( (c = getchar()) && (c != EOF) )
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case STATE_WORD:
                state = inWord( c );
                break;

            case STATE_BLANK:
                state = inBlank( c );
                break;

            case STATE_NUMBER:
                state = inNumber( c );
                break;

            default:
                printf( "state machine contains invalid state\n");
                break;
        } // end switch

        if( '\n' == c )
        {
            break;
        }
    } // end while

    putchar( '\n');
    return 0;
} // end function: main


state_t inWord( char ch )
{
    state_t newState = STATE_WORD;

    if( isdigit( ch ) )
    {
        newState = inNumber( ch );
    }

    else
    {
        putchar( ch );
    }

    return newState;
} // end function: inWord


state_t inBlank( char ch )
{
    state_t newState = STATE_BLANK;

    if( isdigit( ch ) )
    {
        newState = inNumber( ch );
    }

    else if( isalpha( ch ) )
    {
        newState = inWord( ch );
    }

    else
    {
        putchar( ch );
    }

    return newState;
} // end function: inBlank


state_t inNumber( char ch )
{
    state_t newState = STATE_NUMBER;

    if( !isdigit( ch ) )
    {
        printf( "%X ", number );
        newState = inBlank( ch );
    }

    else
    {
        number *=10;
        number += ch-'0';
    }

    return newState;
} // end function: inNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reversal function is creating a number different from what was entered. Change the "+=" to "=" to start. put print statements for readNum and writeNum after the function and you'll see problems

The function also messes up if the entered number is a multiple of 10. You can figure that part out.

Comment: Readnum is stored backwards, that's why revNum is there. I don't try to convert it to hex.

Comment: My bad. I didn't understand the purpose of revNum(). I edited my answer

Comment: No, it should work fine for multiples of 10. Could you give an example of a multiple of 10 that wouldn't work?

Comment: You're right. I noticed that the output was off and assumed it was revNumber() again. Something must be wrong in his state machine somewhere. Its quit a bit of code for a simple task. I dont want to interpret it all...